# Complex argument in Chebyshev polynomials of second kind?

Tags: roots, chebyshev-polynomials, spectra

I am looking at Chebyshev polynomials of second kind in order to characterize the spectra of $2$-Toeplitz perturbed matrices (I am not a mathematician myself, just a control theoretician). In all the references I find that the identity
$U_n(x) = \dfrac{(\sin(n+1)\theta)}{\sin(\theta)}$, with $x=\cos(\theta)$ is defined for $\theta\in\left[0,\pi\right]$.

Now, in some papers I see that the argument of the Chebyshev polynomial $U_n$ seems to be a complex number, how is that even possible? Am I missing something?

Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: $\sin(i)$ is just as much definable as $\sin(1)$, both having a numeric expression. You can use the power series definition for sine to do so. Most definitions of sine extend pretty much trivially to the complex plane, and all such extensions agree by the principle of analytic continuation.

Comment: Thanks, so does that mean that the trigonometric identify for the Chebyshev polynomials still holds for x in the complex plane by simply redefining $\theta$ to be also complex?

Comment: Yup. $\, \, \,$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials) in Wikipedia, the Chebyshev polynomials of the second kind are defined by the recurrence relation
\begin{align}
U_0(x)&=1, \\
U_1(x)&=2x, \\
U_{n+1}(x)&=2x\,U_n(x)-U_{n-1}(x). \tag{1}
\end{align}
If $x=\cos\theta$, one can show that $U_n(x)=\frac{\sin(n+1)\theta}{\sin\theta}$ satisfies $(1)$. On the other hand, one may use the recurrence relation $(1)$ to define $U_n(z)$ for any $z\in\mathbb C$.

Comment: Thanks, so if I understand your point properly, the trigonometric definition of $U_n$ only holds for x being real. Strange, I'll try to contact the authors of some papers because some of the results would then be wrong

Comment: No, that's not my point. One can represent any complex number $z$ as the cosine of a complex number $\theta$ and use the trigonometric representation of $U_n$, but one can also use the recurrence relation $(1)$ to directly compute $U_n(z)$ without having to find the corresponding $\theta$.

Comment: Thank you, all clear now